# 2 functions use the same variables, function 1 checks to see if a & b are undefined, function 2 uses those variables if they are not undefined

Tags: typescript

I have 2 variables a & b;

```
const a:string | undefined = undefined; 
const b:string | undefined = undefined;
```

Those variables get passed as arguments to 2 different functions.
Function 1 checks to see if a & b are undefined and returns false if they are, if not it returns true.

```
const checkIfUndefined = (a:undefined | boolean,b:undefined | boolean):boolean =>{

  if((a && b) === undefined){
    return false; 
  }

  return true
}
```

I am using both of the functions with a turnery operator like this:

```
checkIfFalse(a,b) ? log(a,b) : null;
```

the second function (log) still throws an error because it still thinks a & b are undefined even though second function will only get run if checkIfFalse function will return true.

Is there a way to work around this in typescript?

This is the error im getting:

```
Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'.(2345)
```

Typescript playground link https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLmgJwJZgOYwD4wK5gAmApgGbrGEwC8+RZFhA3DAFCiSwBGSUamOOiXJhKNIQ1HM27cNBjAAFsWABrAJKkAYnAA2EYuIAUiAsMaCU6DABoeZyWNxXMASgRcQIXcThgaAHwA3qysMDCopEYmMABksTBcrjTUtA4ilK4h4eHIxFB4yP6kegYsYTAAvqG5+YX+fHjErNWynDC6IFi0Jrz8tjwuGMnUwW0Q3sQAdJ0YJnauTC2hSioa2qXE80kwAPwdXdvJCDBgeLq6TEA

Comment: The error message doesn't really fit with your thought that it's the `log` call failing. It looks more like a type issue with either the `checkIfUndefined` or `checkIfFalse` function. Can you please try to create a proper [mre] to show us (especially considering the mix of types for `a` and `b`, besides `undefined` are they `string` or `boolean`?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `checkIfFalse(a,b)` does not assert that `a` and `b` are indeed not `undefined`.

You can use a custom type guard to adjust your `checkIfUndefined` method:

```
const checkIfUndefined = (a_value: string | undefined): a_value is string => {
  return a_value !== undefined;
}
```

This function asserts that `a_value` is a `string`, so you'd be able to do this:

```
const log = (a:string) => {
  console.log(a);
}

checkIfUndefined(a) ? log(a) : null;
```

And combined:

```
const a:string | undefined = undefined; 
const b:string | undefined = undefined; 

const checkIfUndefined = (a_value: string | undefined): a_value is string =>{
  return a_value !== undefined;
}

const log = (a:string,b:string) =>{
console.log(a,b);
}

checkIfUndefined(a) && checkIfUndefined(b) ? log(a, b) : null;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLmgJwJZgOYwD4wK5gAmApgGbrGEwC8+RZFhA3DAFCiSwBGSUamOOiXJhKNIQ1HM27cNBjAAFsWABrAJKkAqvRFjaACjgB9AG5wANnmIIYKdFlwFhjAJS2T5q8RioIdvgcaAD4Ab1YYGGRiKDxkMHgzS2sYAEJqWmdJSiZWAF9WWU4YCxAsQ0R7TAAaHiqMVxDwjggQC2IAOlKMI1rXXIL2ZTVNHRcpI0aAMimFYY1tXUYDLkaAfhKy3phVmFswPAsLJiA)

Answer (score 0):

Variables a and b are of type string or undefined, in methods you are accepting values of a and b as boolean | undefined

Comment: I corrected them but still the same problem

Comment: Link provided by you check the log method you have defined a as string it should be a:string|undefined and same for b